# Error: Detected factory 'create_app' in module 'app', but could not call it without arguments. Use 'app:create_app(args)' to specify arguments

Tags: python, flask

I am developing a flask application and recently, I have been trying to run a database magiration using the `Flask-migrate` module. This had been working perfectly in the past, and I had already done a number of migrations.

I was using `Flask-Script` to handle the initialization of the application before. However, when flask stopped supporting flask-Script, I shifted to `Flask-CLI` and started getting this error.

```
Error: Detected factory 'create_app' in module 'app', but could not call it without arguments. Use 'app:create_app(args)' to specify arguments.
```

Here is my `manage.py` file.

```
from app import create_app, db 
from flask_cli import FlaskGroup
import click

from app.auth.models import New_users
from app.models import Role
import os


app=create_app(os.getenv('FLASKCONFIG') or 'default')
cli=FlaskGroup(app)

def make_shell_context():
    return dict(app=app, db=db,User=New_users, Role=Role)

@app.cli.command('test')
@click.argument('name')
def test():
    'Run the unit tests.'
    import unittest
    tests=unittest.TestLoader().discover('tests')
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(tests)

    
if __name__=='__main__':
    cli()
```

You can also check out my `app/__init__.py` file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from config import config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_migrate import Migrate
import os

bootstrap=Bootstrap()
mail=Mail()
login_manager=LoginManager()
login_manager.session_protection='strong'
login_manager.login_view='auth.login'
db=SQLAlchemy()
jwt=JWTManager()
migrate=Migrate()


def create_app(config_name):
    app=Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)
    
    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    jwt.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app,db)
    
    from app.main import main as main_blueprint
    from app.auth import auth as authentication_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(authentication_blueprint, url_prefix='/auth')
    return app
```

Please note that the application runs normally when I use

```
Flask run
```

This happens when I try to run database migrations using

```
flask db migrate -m 'initial Migration'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `flask db` command does not rely on the `manage.py` file, and finds the `create_app` function directly.

I am not familiar with App factories taking arguments like yours does, plus yours could be trivially turned into a no arg function, which should solve this problem.

In `manage.py`

```py
app=create_app()
```

In `app/__init__.py`

```py
def create_app():
    app=Flask(__name__)
    
    config_name = os.getenv('FLASKCONFIG') or 'default'

    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)
```